# Hide and Show TableViewCells properly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am in the process of making a table view controller for my app and it has different headers. 
I am using a custom header view which has a button inside it. The button is used to show the rows for that section. I save the section number of each header in the tag property of the button.

I have looked at more than 20 posts about this but they all say set the height to 0 and hide the cell. That is ridiculous as the auto layout will produce tons of errors and make the app lag a lot.

What I did was to make 2 different cells. One which is used to show my data and the other one is just an empty cell with height of 0.

Then in my code I have a variable called openSection and it holds the current open section number.

So now When I click on the button the current section closes and the new one opens. However there are lots and lots of issues. 
For instance if I scroll up the cells keep changing. 
Next problem is the fact if I open the last header, I cannot scroll up to the first header which is really weird.

This is my function when the button is tapped

```
func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.openSection = sender.tag
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    print("Button tapped")

}
```

This is my cellForRowAt function

```
    if openSection == indexPath.section {
        print("cellForRowAt")
        print(openSection)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "treatmentCell", for: indexPath) as! TreatmentTableViewCell
        cell.name.text = self.treatments[indexPath.section].treatments[indexPath.row].name
        cell.price.text = self.treatments[indexPath.section].treatments[indexPath.row].price
        cell.details.text = self.treatments[indexPath.section].treatments[indexPath.row].details
        return cell

    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "emptyCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.isHidden = true
        return cell
    }
```

and this is my heightForRowAt function

```
    if openSection == indexPath.section {
        print("heightForRowAt")
        print(openSection)

        return self.tableView.rowHeight
    } else {
        return 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this for your button tapped

```
    self.openSection = sender.tag
    let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: openSection)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: self.openSection), with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: index, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
```

And then change your number of rows in section to the code below

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if openSection == section {
        return self.treatments[openSection].treatments.count

    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning 0 from [`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614931-tableview) for a hidden section? You can tell the table view to [`reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614954-reloadsections) when the button is tapped.

Comment: Thank you so much, It works like a damn charm!!!! However the only problem is that it doesn't start from the top. It goes to the bottom of the section. Is there a way to fix that?